# How to fix turbo c++ error "Cannot open include file: graphics.h: no such files or director"

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, turbo-c++, bgi

I had been using turbo c++ compiler in windows xp but i have installed windows 7 yesterday and now i am having a small problem, turbo c++ is not working in window 7 ultimate 64bit. It say "Cannot open include file: graphics.h: no such files or directory" when i wanna include header file.

Comment: How to fix: use a compiler written this decade -- or at least this century.

Comment: or at least in this millennium. Download the file and follow the below answer. But then perhaps it will crib for something included in that file again.

Answer (score 2):

Check your include directory settings and make sure they are referring to the right location and `graphics.h` is in that location. I am assuming you are using

```
#include <graphics.h>
```

rather than

```
 #include "graphics.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the code will need to change (as it was compiling before presumably) but more you need to add some folders to the system include paths.

I am also curious as to why you'd be using TurboC++. I'm still using VC6 at work and I consider that ancient!